# Babelify throws ParseError on import a module from node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm working with `Babelify` and [Browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify). Also, I'm using ES6 style module features by node module system.

I would like to put all my own modules into `node_modules/libs`.

For instance:

`test.js` in `node_modules/libs`

```
export default () => {
  console.log('Hello');
};
```

`main.js` (will be compiled to `bundle.js`)

```
import test from 'libs/test';

test();
```

After that, I have compiled the above codes to `bundle.js` with this command:

```
browserify -t babelify main.js -o bundle.js
```

But unfortunately, I have got some error:

```
export default () => {
^

ParseError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'
```

Directory structure:

```
[test]
  `-- node_modules
  │ `-- libs
  │  `-- test.js
  `-- main.js
```

But, when own modules not in `node_modules` like this:

```
[test]
  `-- libs
  │ `-- test.js
  `-- main.js
```

Then, it works fine. How can I use the ES6 style modules with `babelify` in `node_modules`?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

That is how Browserify transforms work, transforms only have an effect directly in the module that is being referenced.

If you want a module in node_modules to have a transform, you'd need to add a `package.json` to that module and add `babelify` as a transform for that module too. e.g.

```
"browserify": {
  "transform": [
    "babelify"
  ]
},
```

inside your `package.json` plus `babelify` as a dependency will tell `browserify` to run the `babelify` transform on any file inside that module.

Having `libs` be a folder in node_modules is however probably a bad idea. Generally that folder would have true standalone modules in it. I'd generally say that if the folder can't be taken and reused elsewhere, then it shouldn't be in node_modules.

#### Update

For Babel v6, which was recently released, you will also need to specify which transformations you would like to perform on your code. For that, I would recommend creating a `.babelrc` file in your root directory to configure Babel.

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

and

```
npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, libs folder is just store my personal libraries (like internal modules). But is still the bad approach?

Comment: Generally if they are all checked into one repo, I'd expect you to just have a normal subfolder. If they are truly separate libraries, then I'd probably make them separate git repos and reference the github URLs in my package.json.

Comment: hmm, I do have babelify in my package but i still have the same error.

Comment: @nXqd You can import private git repositories as modules with bower too

Comment: @nXqd check my new answer

Comment: It wasn't enought for me, I add presets `"browserify": {
      "transform": [["babelify", { "presets": ["es2015"] } ]]
   }` and that do the trick

Comment: @vincentp Thanks for the bump, updated for Babel 6.x.

Comment: Need to run "npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015" also as pointed out in the link by Jan in the comment of the next answer.

Comment: Found this documentation that maybe useful for people:
https://github.com/babel/babelify#why-arent-files-in-node_modules-being-transformed

What I'm trying to figure out now is how to do this on a global level instead of a per package.json level from within the babelrc file.

Answer (score 5):

> You can specify **source transforms** in the `package.json` in the
>   `browserify.transform` field. There is more information about how
>   source transforms work in package.json on the [module-deps
>   readme](https://github.com/substack/module-deps#transforms).

Source: https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#browserifytransform

---

**Example** (`my_batman_project/node_modules/test_robin_module/package.json`):

```
"browserify": {
  "transform": [
    "babelify"
  ]
},
```

[browserify](/questions/tagged/browserify) will read the configuration and perform any given transforms automatically.

Comment: To build on this answer, I found that I needed an additional step to get this to work with Babel 6.0. As of version 6.0, Babel is a general-purpose platform, and no longer transpiles ES2015 by default. Following the [babel-preset-2015](https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/master/packages/babel-preset-es2015), I created a .babelrc file to load the es2015 preset, which resolve this `ParseError` problem.

Comment: Create .babelrc with the following config to fix ParseError occuring while parsing JSX code.

`{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "stage-1",
    "react"
  ]
}`

Answer (score 4):

I believe this issue is actually related to ESLint.

ESLint 2.0 changed what's required for it to interpret ES6 modules. http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/migrating-to-2.0.0

You'll need to modify your `ecmaFeatures` configuration option and replace it with something like:

```
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
```