# Browserify/Babeljs transformation ignores Nodejs native module

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify, babeljs

Seems like Babeljs transformation does not import native NodeJS modules, I am trying to include fs, but getting exception:

```
fs.readFile is not a function
```

Sample code to read file:

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile("test.txt", function (err, data) {
});
```

Command to run babel transformation:

```
watchify app/app.js -t babelify -o app/js/bundle.js
```

I think it's related to problem described here: [Babelify throws ParseError on import a module from node_modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30386317/babelify-throws-parseerror-on-import-a-module-from-node-modules) , but I can't apply it to native module.

Comment: This is a browserify issue, not a Babel one. If you're running this in a browser, what are you expecting `fs.readFile` to do?

Comment: @loganfsmyth well agree, but I am running it inside electron app.